# http: unexpected EOF reading trailer while reading large files

Tags: go, https, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to read uploaded files from Go endpoint.

```
func UploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {    
        logger.LLogger.Errorf(err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

The code works fine for files around 7-8 MB but if upload larger files 9MB and more then I see FormFile returning error,

> http: unexpected EOF reading trailer

Comment: Do you use a standard Go http package only? What do you use to upload the file?

Comment: Yes I am using standard "net/http". The upload request is in the following format,
`form.append("file", fs.createReadStream(filePath)); uploadStatus = await axios.post(this.getUploadUrl(), form, request_config);`

Comment: Please, try to use a different client to rule out a client-side: curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/upload \
  -F "file=@/Users/appleboy/test.zip" \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"

Comment: Yes I tried the above curl command and it works as expected and the file gets uploaded correctly.

Comment: Great! It means that the problem is most probably on the NodeJS side. What do the logs day?

Comment: From the logs I just see when using the Nodejs, the FormFile returns err and the err message is **http: unexpected EOF reading trailer**. Incase of curl it just goes through perfectly.

Comment: Also here is the request captured in server side code, 


1. Curl case (successfull case) 
`POST /uploadfile HTTP/1.1\nHost: server.default:8075\nuser-agent: curl/7.74.0\naccept: */*\ncontent-length: 22686187\ncontent-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------96a7a60e19618256\nexpect: 100-continue"`. 
    
2. NodeJs case (Failure case)
`POST uploadfile HTTP/1.1\nHost: server.default:8075\naccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\ncontent-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------431911039690949780958592\nuser-agent: axios/0.19.2\nconnection: close`

Comment: @AndreyDyatlov I have server code (endpoint)  in one pod lets say X, and client in another pod lets say Y, curl fails if done from Y to X for files more than 8-10 MB but curls succeeds if done from inside pod X (using localhost). Is this related to some kubernetes network issue?

Comment: Try to check the `NetworkPolicy` configured in your cluster. Also, if the pods communicate through some ingress proxy (they really shouldn't if they are in the same cluster), then check the ingress configuration.